# C# .NET 3.5 Get Generic Definition

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I have the following class

```
public class AbstractJobDao<T> where T : IJob {
  protected T buildJob() {
    // create an IJob implementation instance based on the generic parameter        
  }      
}

public class FullTimeJobDao : AbstractJobDao<FullTimeJob> {      
}

public class InternshipDao : AbstractJobDao<Internship> {      
}
```

Both **FullTimeJob** and **Internship** implement the **IJob** interface.  I'd like the buildJob() method to be able to infer the generic in the Dao implementation class using reflection, and then create an instance of that type.  Is there a way to do this using reflection in .NET 3.5?

If so, what should the line/lines of code look like in the buildJob() method?

EDIT -- I think I'm not clear on my question.  What I want is for when buildJob() is called inside of the FullTimeJobDao, to create an instance of FullTimeJob.  When buildJob() is called from inside of InternshipDao, it should create an instance of Internship, based on the generic type as defined at the top of the class.

Comment: Type.GenericTypeArguments + Activator.CreateInstance()

Comment: voroninp's comment above is the answer i'm looking for here.  thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have should almost work, except you don't require your generic argument to be instantiable. If you add that as a constraint, you should be able to use `new`:

```
public class AbstractJobDao<T> where T : IJob, new() {
  protected T buildJob() {
    return new T();
  }      
}
```

Alternatively, if you have some reason why that constraint is not appropriate in your situation, you can use [`Activator.CreateInstance`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0hcyx2kd%28v=vs.90%29.aspx):

```
public class AbstractJobDao<T> where T : IJob {
  protected T buildJob() {
    return Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
  }      
}
```

Comment: The first one will be compiled into first one

Comment: @ViacheslavSmityukh It is what the compiler exists for. 1 <-> 2 better I think ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You have to declare your `AbstractJobDao` class this way :

```
public class AbstractJobDao<T> where T : IJob, new() {
  protected T buildJob() {
    return new T();
  }      
}
```

Note the `new()` after `IJob` : this way, you're indicating that parameter `T` :

1. Implements `IJob`'s methods
2. Offers a constructor with no argument.

So the compiler will allow you to use `new T()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create IJob factory to implement it

```
interface IJobFactory
{
  IJob Create();
}

class FullTimeJobFactory
  : IJobFactory
{
  IJob Create()
  {
    return new FullTimeJob();
  }
}

class InternshipJobFactory
  : IJobFactory
{
  IJob Create()
  {
    return new InternshipJob();
  }
}
```

now you can use abstract factoy IJobFactory to create instancies of abstract IJob

```
public class AbstractJobDao<T> where T : IJob {
  public AbstractJobDao(IJobFactory<T> factory)
  {
  }

  protected IJobFactory<T> Factory{get;set;}

  protected T buildJob() {
    return Factory.Create();
  }      
}

public class FullTimeJobDao : AbstractJobDao<FullTimeJob> {

  public FullTimeJobDao()
    : base(new FullTimeJobFactory())
  {}     
}

public class InternshipDao : AbstractJobDao<Internship> {
  public InternshipDao ()
    : base(new InternshipJobFactory())
  {}

}
```

Comment: I think I'm not clear on my question.What I want is for when buildJob() is called inside of the FullTimeJobDao, to create an instance of FullTimeJob.  When buildJob() is called from inside of InternshipDao, it should create an instance of Internship, based on the generic type as defined at the top of the class.

Comment: `default(T)` is simply `null`.

Comment: Yeah, that won't do what I want I don't think.  I hope my EDIT above is more clarifying.

Comment: I still think I'm not clear on what I want.  Forgetting about creating the instance for a second, is there a way to infer the generic type from the FullTimeJobDao class (which should give me the FullTimeJob type)?